# ArcGIS Network Analyst Service Area Default breaks in Meters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I'm trying to use a meter value for the default break. The default value in length is Kilometers, and I can't figure out how to change that.

Additionally, the field doesn't allow a **dot** or a **comma**.

I need to create an catchment area for 600m, 1200m, 1800m.

How would I do this?

Comment: Use the Break_Units to change metres it is supported in the Distance Attribute parameter http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Generate_Service_Areas/00480000001w000000/

Comment: Thank you Mapperz that worked, I just had to use the **generate service area** not the default **make service area**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **Break_Units** to change metres it is supported in the *Distance Attribute parameter*

> default_break_values (Optional)
>
> Default impedance values indicating the extent of the service area to
>   be calculated. The default can be overridden by specifying the break
>   value on the facilities.
>
> Multiple polygon breaks can be set to create concentric service areas.
>   For instance, to find 2-, 3-, and 5-minute service areas for the same
>   facility, specify "2 3 5" as the value for the Default break values
>   parameter (the numbers 2, 3, and 5 should be separated by a space).

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Generate_Service_Areas/00480000001w000000/